# LINQ - Limit result based on count returned by custom function

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code and want to return a limited subset of this query in LINQ.  The limited subset will take u.ID as an argument to the function and count the number of records associated with u.ID from another table.

So far, this is what I have.

```
 var res = from u in db.Users
                      where  id == u.WorkGroupID && jobCount(u.ID) > 0
                      select
                new
                {
                    ArtistID = u.ID,
                    ArtistName = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName
                };
```

How can I modify this query to limit the number of returned records based on a count value associated with each u.ID?

EDIT:

New Query Below.  Last line returns to caller a list from the last LINQ query.

```
  var res = from u in db.Users
                      where  id == u.WorkGroupID
                      select
                new
                {
                    // SELF
                    ArtistID = u.ID,
                    ArtistName = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName
                };

            var res2 = res.ToList<dynamic>();
            var res3 = from row in res2.AsEnumerable()
                       where jobCount(row.ArtistID) > 0
                       select new
                         {
                             row.ArtistName,
                             row.ArtistID
                        };

            return res3.ToList<dynamic>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a group join:

```
from u in db.Users
join o in db.Other on u.ID equals o.UserID into grp
where grp.Any()
select new
{
    ArtistID = u.ID,
    ArtistName = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName
};
```

Comment: Thanks Cory for the response.  I got the query to respond. I tried another method which I have posted (edit to my post).  I will need to verify that this works correctly but so far I do not see any values with 0 count.  I am really new to LINQ and so I am thinking very primitive and using existing code.  I will continue to investigate this.  I will vote up.  Maybe my approach is a bit unnecessary.

Comment: I just edited it to use `Any()` instead of `Count() > 0`. SQL Optimizer likely fixed it for me anyway, but in theory it'll perform better.